# Db exception handling in php

Tags: php, database, exception

So I have a class for each table in a database. Now I want to create the table in the database if it doesn't exist yet.

```
   try {
        $result = r\db($this->databaseName);

        $result = $result->tableCreate($this->tableName);

        $result = $result->run($manager);

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        //throw new \Exception("Error: $e");
    }
```

This echo's:

```
Runtime error: Table `customers` already exists.
```

What would be a proper way to catch this specific error and resume the program, but still being able to catch other errors.

Comment: echo is not exception so you should first check if table exist and after that create new or do nothing...

Comment: So you're saying I should do a "find" call to the database first? And I know echo is not an exception but I did that to retrieve the exception message. The database drivers itself already throws an exception.

Comment: right, sorry i didn't look carefully.. yes why calling create table if it exist already ?

Comment: `SHOW TABLES LIKE 'table_name'` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-tables.html

Comment: or `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`

Comment: @Kazz I am using a NoSQL solution.

Comment: oh.. `echo get_class($e);` - this will echo class of object $e, then you can catch only specific class, for example: `catch (\TableAlreadyExistException $e) {}`. if class is basic one just `Exception` you can check exception message if it contains some specific words (pattern) and act depend on it... if you catch exception program will not stop (if you don't throw another one)... also you can throw the exact same like `catch (... $e) { throw $e; }`